# PGFplots/groupplots: Understanding the commands dominance of the colorbar ticks style

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

### With groupplots

When plotting group plots with colorbar, I used `major y tick style` in the global `groupplot` options and `y tick  style` in the `colorbar style={}`.

However, for colorbar style, I found that pgfplots always looks first for `major y tick style` while ignoring `y tick style` as seen in this MWE.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
            y tick style = {black,ultra thick},
            major y tick  style={red,ultra thick},
        ]
        %
        \nextgroupplot [
            colorbar left,
            colorbar style ={
                    tick align = outside,
                    y tick  style={blue,thin},% <<< this definition has no effect at all
                },
        ]
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
            domain=-1:1,
            domain y=-2:2,
        ] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
    \end{groupplot}
    %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Therefore, the only way to forcibly change the colorbar style is to use `major y tick style` instead of `y tick style`

```
colorbar style ={
                    tick align = outside,
                    major y tick  style={blue,thin},
                },
```

[image]

However, when setting the option of `y tick  style={draw=none}`

```
colorbar style ={
                    tick align = outside,
                    y tick  style={draw=none},
                },
```

, pgfplots accepts its option and draws nothing

[image]

So, my main question is why pgfplots always ignores `y tick style` in favor of `major y tick style` except in case of `y tick style={draw=none}`?

My other question is what is the meaning of `y tick style`? is it the style of major tick, minor tick or both?

---

### Without groupplots

In case of a normal plot without groupplots, `y tick style` works as expected and can change the colorbar style without any intervention from `major y tick style`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            y tick style = {black,ultra thick},
            major y tick  style={red,ultra thick},
            colorbar left,
            colorbar style ={
                    tick align = outside,
                    y tick  style={blue,thin},% <<< works fine
                },
        ]
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
            domain=-1:1,
            domain y=-2:2,
        ] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
    \end{axis}
    %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting behavior, indeed. A quick "fix" for the `groupplots` part is to replace `colorbar style={y tick  style=...}` by `colorbar style={major y tick  style=...}`

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for your comment; I already said in my question that this is the only way to forcibly impose my style `:)`

Comment: Oh sorry, that was the part of your question that I didn't fully understand ...